# Magento CE - Tax Rule based upon several required Product Classes

Tags: magento-1.9, tax-class

I am new to Magento and trying to setup Tax Rules based upon certain product combinations in the basket.

There are three possible tax valuations that I am trying to apply:

STANDARD which is 20% and applied to all "default" users and products.
ZERO which is 0% applied to products with the "Assistive" class and applies only to "Registered" users.
COMPOSITE which is 4% and only applies when "Assistive" class products are chosen with "Hardware" class and "Installation" class products.
1 and 2 are standard tax rules and have been setup. What I am having difficulty working out is how to create a tax rule which requires more than one Product Class for it to apply.

Is this possible with the core Magento or would it require an additional extension?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of tax rules does not exists in the core, sorry.

I don't know if an extension exist to match your need, but most of the time it can be solved by using a bundle product.

A bundle product with a "composite" tax class where you have to pick at least one "assistive", one "installation" and one "hardware" products.

Hope that can help.

Comment: I appreciate the tip but I don't think a bundle product solution is workable for the products involved. Installation need only be included once as would the hardware product where as there could be multiple assistive products.

The hardware is usually a laptop and installation is not always included. This is why a tax rule(s) requiring the inclusion of certain product classes would be a cleaner solution as I could cover all eventualities and apply one of the three VAT rates as required.